# How to check whether 2 'combined' values already exist in a nested associative array

Tags: php

I have a text file I'm reading and treating line by line and I wish to put the resultant variables (post treatment) into a nested array, so for each new line of the text file a new index will be created in the array with 2 values being placed into the nested associative array - so far so good.

```
$arr = file('file.txt') or die('ERROR: Cannot find file');
$add_data = array(array('opc'=>$outward_pc,'lkey'=>$lkey));
$i=0;

foreach ($arr as $line) {

    $outward_pc = trim(substr($line,0,4));
    $lkey = trim(substr($line,15,6));

    $add_data[$i]['opc'] = $outward_pc;
    $add_data[$i]['lkey'] = $lkey;

    $i++;
}
```

However, the tricky part comes when I only want to add those 2 variables to the nested array if their combined values are unique
**e.g.** from the variable pairs below I would only want to add 4 new indexes to the array as the combinations 'AB10' and '000002', 'AB10' and '000004', and 'AB21' and '000003' both appear more than once

```
'AB10' and '000002'
'AB10' and '000002'
'AB10' and '000004'
'AB10' and '000004'
'AB21' and '000002'
'AB21' and '000003'
'AB21' and '000003'
```

I think because I'm dealing with a nested (and associative) array any form of literature on the web is proving hard to come by, particularly with regards to how to correctly write the !in_array function.
I've failed miserably so far to come up with anything close to the right syntax. My (admittedly poor) flailing around is shown below:

```
if (!in_array(array($outward_pc, $lkey), $add_data)) {

    $add_data[$i]['opc'] = $outward_pc;
    $add_data[$i]['lkey'] = $lkey;

}
```

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a concatenation of the two values and use that as the key in your `$add_data` array.  That way duplicate values would just overwrite each other.

```
foreach ($arr as $line) {

    $outward_pc = trim(substr($line,0,4));
    $lkey = trim(substr($line,15,6));
    $key = $outward_pc . $lkey;

    $add_data[$key]['opc'] = $outward_pc;
    $add_data[$key]['lkey'] = $lkey;
}
```

Comment: and call `array_values($add_data)` to strip off the string keys when you're done.

Comment: And I would suggest a delimiter like `$outward_pc . "|" . $lkey` so values like `AB10, 0004` and `AB1, 00004` don't conflict.

Comment: Genius (as far as I'm concerned anyway...)! Great solution, thanks very much to the pair of you for your invaluable aid. Will definitely need to make use of the delimiter and I can also see the value of array_values in this instance, which I've never had to use before. Thanks again chaps.